# Constructor of derived class calling constructor of base class

Tags: c++, object, constructor, default-constructor

In the following code, when I try to create an object of `Obiektstatyczny`, the constructor of `Miasto` (base class) is being called.

```
class Miasto
{
    public:
    Miasto();
    int rozmiar;
};


class Obiektstatyczny :public Miasto
{
    std::vector <Obiektstatyczny> blokowisko;
    int x, y;
public: 
    Obiektstatyczny();
};


Obiektstatyczny::Obiektstatyczny()
{
    for (int i = 2; i < rozmiar; i++)
        for (int j = 2; j < rozmiar; j++)
            blokowisko.push_back(Blok(i, j));
}

Miasto::Miasto()
{
    cin >> iloscBlokow;
    cin >> szerokoscBloku;
    rozmiar = iloscBlokow*szerokoscBloku;

    mapa.assign(rozmiar, vector<int>(rozmiar));
    bufor.assign(rozmiar, vector<int>(rozmiar));

    for (int i = 0; i<rozmiar; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < rozmiar; j++)
            mapa[i][j]=bufor[i][j]=0;
}
```

I think the reason is that I was trying to create the new `Obiektstatyczny` object by itself, not through the base class, thus the program kept repeating itself. However, I don't know a way to do this properly. My attempts to do this failed miserably.

I tried to create a field inside the `Miasto` class containing `Obiektstatyczny`, and then initializing it in a method of `Miasto`, but i got
"unknown override specifier" error.

```
Obiektstatyczny obj;
void initializeObj()
    {
        obj = Obiektstatyczny();
    }
```

Comment: I don't completely get what's the surprising point with your question? The base class constructor of course is called before the derived class constructor is entered. There's no need to `new` a _superclass instance_, and your try to do that ends up in an infinite recursion.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. 'Failed miserably' is not a problem description. I don't know what you mean by 'not through the base class'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is this:

```
struct X
{
    std::vector<X> stuff;
    X();
}
```

That is, an object contains a list of objects of the same type. This is not an immediate problem, but you need to be careful with such code.

If you create a non-empty list in the constructor

```
X::X()
{
    stuff.push_back(X());
    stuff.push_back(X());
    stuff.push_back(X());
    stuff.push_back(X());
}
```

this creates a logical error: to make an object, you need to make 4 objects; to make each of these objects, you need to make 4 other objects, ...

If the constructor doesn't fill the `vector` with actual objects, and leaves it empty, no immediate problem will occur. So you might want to move your code that generates a non-empty list into a separate function, e.h. `init()`. Or a separate constructor:

```
X::X()
{
    // leave stuff empty
}

X::X(size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        stuff.push_back(X()); // each of the created objects has empty stuff
}
```

Comment: That seems like a solution to my problem. Is there a way to move
`std::vector<X> stuff` from derived class to base class without getting 

*undeclared identifier* and
*not a valid template type argument for parameter*

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question for that. It's unrelated to this question. Make sure you present a [mcve] so people don't have to guess what your actual problem is.